# BigQuery: INSERT INTO datasets in another server location

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, etl

I have a project called project-a, and datasets called product_eu (EU Server), and table name called table_eu.

I have another dataset called product_us (US Server) and table in that dataset called table_us.

The SQL queries of the 2 tables are almost the same with the only difference in source tables.

If I want to join table_us in EU location, what will you do? I tried to ETL directly to the EU location:

```
INSERT INTO  `project-a.product_eu.table_us`
SEL *
FROM abc
```

But I found the following error:

```
Not found: Dataset project-a:product_eu was not found in location US
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this.

You need to transfer the EU dataset to US, and copy from `table_EU` to `table_US`.

See ways you can accomplish [copy/transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#regional-locations).